# Selecting notification in same activity as PendingIntent, but different ViewPage

Tags: android

**Scenario:**
My app has one activity which contains a ViewPager, that shows two fragments (call it Page A and Page B).

**Problem:**
When an event in the background triggers a notification for Page A, and the user is on Page B, selecting the Notification *does nothing*; i.e. there's no callback to onCreate(), onResume(), onNewIntent(), onResumeFragments(), or onStart() and the user stays on Page B.

**Question:**

- How is it possible to make the ViewPager show Page A when the user
  has selected the notification and is on Page B?

or

- Is it possible, within the Activity, to detect when the user has
  selected the notification that points to that same activity?

**Code for Notification:**

```
// Create a notification
    final Context ctx = this;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, ActivityMain.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_NOTIFICATION, true);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Resources res = ctx.getResources();

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, REQUESTCODE_ACTIVITYMAIN_LISTFRAGMENT, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)//required
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.notification_title))//required
                .setContentText(data.description)//required
                .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.notification_title))
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    notificationManager.notify(mNotificationID, notification);
```

Maybe there's a flag/configuration that can be added to the notification intent to force the Activity to recognize the selected notification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a bit of effort, but here's the solution to switch ViewPager tabs when a Notification is selected for an activity *that is already running in the foreground* :

**1) create Notification with the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and an extra to show that a notification launched this activity**

```
// Create a notification
final Context ctx = this;
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, ActivityMain.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_NOTIFICATION, true);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//see rest of code in my question to create the notification
```

**2) Update the manifest with `singleTop` for the activity**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.cool.app.ActivityMain"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" >
</activity>
```

**3) Within `ActivityMain` (or whatever your activity is) override onNewIntent()**

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    Log.i(TAG,"onNewIntent");
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);//needed so that getIntent() doesn't return null inside onResume()
}
```

**4) Within `ActivityMain` (or whatever your activity is) override onResume() and include logic to switch tabs**

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    // Test if a Notification caused this activity to launch - if so then select the first tab
    // NOTE: we get here from a notification by using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        final boolean bIsLaunchedFromNotification = extras.getBoolean(INTENT_EXTRA_NOTIFICATION);
        if (bIsLaunchedFromNotification)
        {
            final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
        }
    }
}
```

**5) for good form - within ActivityMain (or Application), define the constant to pass the extra with**

```
final public static String INTENT_EXTRA_NOTIFICATION = "fromNotification";
```